# How to show onclick button animation layout in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I want to show a transparent layout over the screen when a button is pressed.

I tried by using Stack and it works fine, but when I pressed the button inside of the function(eg. `ExercisePage()`) the overlay doesn't show.

The overlay works when the value `overlayShouldBeVisible==true`. 
But changing the value of `overlayShouldBeVisible` from inside the `ExercisePage()`, button pressed event, the overlay doesn't appear.

```
Stack(
      fit: StackFit.passthrough,
      children: <Widget>[

        ExercisePage(),

       overlayShouldBeVisible==true?new CorrectWrongOverlay(isCorrect) : new Container() ,
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're doing inside ExercisePage() but I can give you some advice. Try to use value notifierin order to change the value of a variable https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html

Based on the overlayShouldBeVisible value, you can use the if condition to show CorrectWrongOverlay or not without put another widget in the tree.